# Problems with using getSheetByName function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to import data from Google Sheets files in a folder.

Some of the files in this folder do not have the sheet name "purchase order" in the file, so I am getting null responses.

```
function import() {
   var spreadsheets = DriveApp.
     getFolderById("1AE-GotVyCaxlEF04kfedXytn65oxJ2hi").
     getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);

    var data = [];
    while (spreadsheets.hasNext()) {
      var currentSpreadsheet = 
      SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheets.next().getId());
      data = data.concat(currentSpreadsheet.   
        getSheetByName("Purchase order").
        getRange("A13:H50").
        getValues());
    }

    SpreadsheetApp.
      getActiveSheet().
      getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).
      setValues(data);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve]). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: What's the question? Your code shows no attempt to handle the cases where that sheet name doesn't exist - are we supposed to guess what should happen in those cases and write code that handles it?

Comment: What's the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this.
Look at pushing the data you want into an array and writing the array to a spreadsheet.

```
    function import() {
   var spreadsheets = DriveApp.
     getFolderById("1AE-GotVyCaxlEF04kfedXytn65oxJ2hi").
     getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);

    var data = [];
    while (spreadsheets.hasNext()) {
      var currentSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheets.next().getId());
      var sheetName = currentSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
      if (sheetName === "Purchase order"){ 
      data = data.concat(currentSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Purchase order").getRange("A13:H50").getValues());
      } else{continue} //edit made
    }

    SpreadsheetApp.
      getActiveSheet().
      getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).
      setValues(data);
  }
```

Comment: Your approach fails to address the issue OP is facing, namely that a sheet with the given name may not be present (in which case calling methods on the variable will fail).

Comment: Hmm you are right. Should add an else{continue}. This will skip the sheet if it is not called Purchase order.

Comment: You are confusing a `Spreadsheet` class object and a `Sheet` class object